# What is the activation energy of iron rust?

Tags: kinetics, transition-metals

Iron rusts to Geothite (FeO(OH)). What is the activation energy for this reaction? Where can I find this information?

Comment: Try google scholar.   Iron can rust to many things under many conditions.  This question is broad.

Comment: It is **goethite**. As for the activation energy, I don't believe it is even _defined_ here. The reaction is too complex.

Comment: @Agriculturist Any single activation energy for any product.

Comment: In that case google "Activation energy for iron oxide"